# Singleton instance being garbage collected?

Tags: android, singleton, fragment

I thought a singleton instance should not be garbage collected, however I maintained a singleton object, and mark it when it was initialized, like this:

```
private static LocalCache instance;

public LocalCache() {
    // initialize objects......
}

public static LocalCache getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LocalCache();
        Log.e("instance", "new");
    }
    return instance;
}
```

I found that this log appear more than once in my application.
More precisely, I have 5 fragments in a FragmentActivity. When I press home button to do some task and switch back to the activity, the singleton class seems to be reallocated. Is there thing wrong in my code? Or can I prevent the fragment being recreated?
I'm sure I didn't assign null to the instance.

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    Log.e("finalize", "finalize");
}
```

I also override `finalize()` to observe when it was destroyed, but the log didn't appear before the second "new instance" log.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there thing wrong in my code?

Usually, for a singleton, you use `synchronized` and `volatile` for locking, to make sure that you do not allocate multiple instances due to parallel calls on multiple threads. Or, in your case, just use a static initializer, since your `getInstance()` does not take any parameters needed to instantiate your `LocalCache`.

However, more likely, the issue here is that your process was terminated. Once you are no longer in the foreground, your process can be terminated at any point. When your app runs again, a new process is created, and all static data members will initially be `null`.

Comment: When I switch back to the activity, it is the same tab that selected before I put the activity to background, I don't think the process was terminated......

Comment: @Leonhart: "When I switch back to the activity, it is the same tab that selected before I put the activity to background" -- depending on how you "switch back to the activity", you will wind up at "the same tab" regardless of whether the process was terminated or not. Notably, if you use the recent-tasks list, that should return you to whatever activity was on top of the back stack for that task.

Comment: I use ViewPagerAdapter to store the index of tab selected, so I assume it the whole process has not been destroyed, and neither does the singleton?

Comment: @Leonhart: If you use the recent-tasks list, your activity will be handed the saved instance state `Bundle` and therefore may well restore itself to the last page that you were on in the `ViewPager`.

Comment: I use home button to switch out, and press the icon of application to switch back. Also I found something weird, I override `finalize()` to observe when it was destroyed, but the log didn't appear before the second "new instance" log.

Comment: @CommonsWare , I have experience a similar issue. When the application is in background (Pressing the home key) for a long time and then it is restore all the data in it goes blank. Here the data was store in a Singleton (static). I had already passed an Application context to the singleton in the getInstance(..) method.

Any way to get across this and force the application to start from the launcher activity again to reload the static variable and hence the Singleton?